# Redirecting subdomains to their corresponding folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to configure `.htaccess` so any subdomain will be redirected to it's corresponding folder without need to edit `.htaccess` file every time I want to add the subdomain? How?

```
foo.domain.com -> /subdomains/foo
bar.domain.com -> /subdomains/bar

anything.domain.com/file.txt -> /subdomains/anything/file.txt
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!subdomains/).*)$ subdomains/%1/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Did you get this to work, Martin?  
I am trying to do something very similar (get example.mydomain.com to use the php stored under www.mydomain.com) and I am finding putting a rewrite of:  
    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.mydomain.com$`  
    `RewriteRule  ^something.html$ /public_html/action/something.php [L]`  
(where the www site is stored in public_html and the example site is stored in its sister folder and the above is in the .htaccess in the parent of the 2 folders) does not work

Comment: (ran out of char)  
BUT I can use the rewrite to send to another domain:  
    `RewriteRule  ^something.html$ http://www.example.com/something.php [L]`  
works.  
I dont think the site can be given access to the PHP from the higher folder level?  
Has anyone gotten this working?  
(why is formatting not working?!? :( )

Comment: @LeadeGroot: Suggest you open a new question since reading .htaccess from comments isn't easy.